# Using Google Apps Script and Google URL shortener API to get click analytics

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-url-shortener

in Apps Script, I would like to fetch click statistics for previously generated short URLs via the [Google URL shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started).

I'm afraid I don't really get the API documentation. This is what I tried:

```
  function GetShortUrlClicks() {

  var analytics = UrlShortener.Url.get('http://goo.gl/WPN7wo').getAnalytics();
  var clicks = analytics.getAllTime();
  Logger.log(clicks)
  }
```

It seems that the variable analytics is undefined and thus the next line throws an error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the optional args required to get the Analytics data back.

This function ought to work -

```
function GetShortUrlClicks() {
  var analytics = UrlShortener.Url.get('http://goo.gl/WPN7wo',{projection:'FULL'}).getAnalytics();
  var clicks = analytics.getAllTime();
  Logger.log(clicks)
}
```

You can use more see more reference here - https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/get

Comment: Great. Mark this question as this accepted so that this will help other developers in the future.